# Rails - YAML Validation for Serialized Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, serialization

I have a form for a model with a serialized hash. The form includes a text area for entering YAML, in order to edit the hash that is then serialized.

Is there an easy way to put together some validation on the model to ensure the supplied YAML is valid, so that the model doesn't save and record the error when you try to mass-assign the YAML to the serialized member?

So, controller something like this:

```
def foobar_params
  params.require(:foobar).permit(:hash)
  # params[:foobar][:hash] will be YAML/JSON/etc
end

def update_foobar
  if @foobar.update_attributes(foobar_params)
    render text: "Success!"
  else
    render text: @foobar.errors.messages.join(", ")
  end
end
```

and a model something like:

```
class Foobar < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :serialized_field
end
```

I want to validate that `params[:foobar][:hash]` is valid YAML/JSON/etc, and if it's not, stop the `update_attributes` and properly record the error in `@foobar.errors`, while all the while `foobar.serialized_field` is a `Hash`

What's a good, rails-y, succinct way to do this?